# Ruby on Rails - ActiveRecord validates presence if 'self.preference.present?' doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'd like to write a validation for preference. It should validate the presence of :city (which is associated with belongs_to) in the case if a preference record for this user exists.

*user.rb*

```
# attributes
# :city, :string
has_one :preference
```

*preference.rb*

```
# attributes
# preferred_car_brand
belongs_to :user
```

I tried this, but records get saved without an error.

*user.rb*

```
validates :city, presence: true, if: :user_preference_exists

def user_preference_exists
  self.preference.present?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to validate the presence of a field.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :city, presence: true
end
```

It won't let active record save user model with empty value for :city.

Comment: I've missed to say that preference should be an "optional relation". There 're users whith preference and there're users without preference. I only want to validate if user has a preference. I updated the question.

Comment: I had a mistake in my model which turned out that city was not blank and therefore the validation could not spawn an error, your approach works!